# Como retornar todos os campos de uma linha "Mysql" pelo "id" da linha?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Dada uma tabela "Mysql", onde existem 3 campos: ID - Nome - Sobrenome

Como deve ser a consulta de modo que apenas informando o ID, ela retorna todos os campos da linha ?

Nota: coloquei apenas 3 campos para exemplo, mas a consulta deve servir para uma linha que possui inúmeros campos.

Comment: Seria só colocar o asterico (`*`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Baseado no comentário, para exibir as colunas no html de forma dinâmica pode usar a função `array_keys()` que retorna os nomes das chaves e com elas fazer um segundo foreach para exibir os valores.

```
$registros =[
        ['id' => 1, 'nome' => 'alberto'],
        ['id' => 2, 'nome' => 'beto'],
        ['id' => 3, 'nome' => 'carlos'],

];

foreach($registros as $item){
    $campos = array_keys($item);
    foreach($campos as $valor){
        echo $item[$valor] .'<br>';
    }
}
```

Um exemplo mais proxixo da realidade seria o código abaixo, ele pode ser abstraido para função.

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from paineladm_usuarios") or die(mysql_error());

echo '<table border="1">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $campos = array_keys($row);
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($campos as $campo){
        echo '<td>'. $row[$campo] .'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Utilizei o seguinte código : $registros = mysql_query("select * from paineladm_usuarios");  
foreach($registros as $item){
    $campos = array_keys($item);
    foreach($campos as $valor){
        echo $item[$valor] .'<br>';
    }
} porém aparece um erro de argumento inválido no foreach(), consegue enxergar o meu erro?
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @MagicHat deixei um exemplo simples pq vc não colocou nenhum código na pergunta mas posso adaptar o exemplo para o uso real. `$registros` tem a estrutura de array retornado pelo banco.

Comment: Mals ae, com esse código que coloquei no comentário já dá pra desenvolver algo? No aguardo...

Comment: @MagicHat editei a resposta, agora já sai em formato de tabela é so definir o cabeçalho das colunas pode usara mesma tecnica.

Comment: Perfeito, agora só vou adaptar pro msqli...Vlw x)

Comment: @MagicHat isso mesmo :D

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro faz a conexão iniciando um Objeto Mysqli

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Cria o select

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * From tabela where ID = 'Coloca o ID aqui'");
```

Dá a fetchiada para poder mostrar no HTML

```
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

E echa tudo na moralzinha

```
    foreach($row as $echada_na_moral) {
        echo $echada_na_moral['id'];
        echo $echada_na_moral['nome'];
        echo $echada_na_moral['Sobrenome'];
}
```

Comment: Então "Dom" , nessa parte de echa tudo é que é o penalty pra mim, a linha tem trocentos campos, num tem um jeito de tipo:"Enquanto existe campos nessa linha desse ID, echa sozinho, automático ? Saca o problema? Valew pela atenção...

Comment: pode fazer somente com o $echada_na_moral, mas você não consegue controlar a formatação dos campos duas dicas primeira: htmlspecialchars($echada_na_moral) vai te ajudar com html, a segunda é se precisar disso em JSON escreve echo json_encode($row)