# Como exibir no html os dados de todas as colunas obtidas através de uma query mysql?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tenho uma tabela com 1000 colunas(exemplo), como exibir o conteúdo , de todos as colunas de uma linha obtida através do "ID"?

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela_1000_colunas` WHERE id = 1;
```

Após este select, como eu exibo no "html" o conteúdo dessas 1000 colunas?
Ex: coluna1 coluna2 coluna3...coluna999 coluna1000
     dado1   dado2   dado3     dado999    dado1000

Comment: Não é a mesma [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128962/91), uma sugestão é pegar os nomes dos campos através do `array_keys()` e fazer outro foreach que itere esse array, assim fica dinâmico.

Answer (score 0):

Eu exibo desta forma, veja o código abaixo:

```
echo'<table align ="center" class="bortpago" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">';

for($x=0;$x<1000;$x++) {   
  echo 
        '<tr bgcolor="#BEBEBE" >'
            .'<td>'                               
            .coluna[1]  
            .'</td>'
            .'<td>'
            .coluna[2]   
            .'</td>'
        .'</tr>';
}
```

Comment: $query = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM paineladm_usuarios");
 
while ($coluna = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      $coluna = $coluna["Field"];
     echo "$coluna ";
}

    


mysql_close();
esse codigo retorna o nome das 1000 colunas automaticamente, eu queria ao inves do nome da coluna os valores de todas as colunas nessa linha